# Unable to login with newly created user in keycloak

Tags: docker, keycloak

I am following this tutorial

https://www.keycloak.org/getting-started/getting-started-docker

I managed to bring up `keycloak server` using the following command

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:20.0.2 start-dev
```

on my local machine and login to console via `http://localhost:8080`

I am able to login using the `admin` user. Post that, I created a `realm` and a `new user` and set the credentials, however, I am unable to login via newly created user. *(Marked it enable while creating)* The error I see in docker logs is

```
2022-12-21 14:23:00,184 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (executor-thread-17) type=LOGIN_ERROR, realmId=f5e9717b-0eeb-47cf-9d9b-2f697416c841, clientId=account-console, userId=null, ipAddress=172.17.0.1, error=user_not_found, auth_method=openid-connect, auth_type=code, redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/realms/master/account/?referrer=security-admin-console&referrer_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fadmin%2Fmaster%2Fconsole%2F%23%2Fmyrealm%2Fusers%2F9d6a5677-3767-4bce-a5bb-db20fe2c7ac5%2Fsessions#/, code_id=aa9ac3df-dadc-4abc-bfea-022b27ca35f0, username=harsh, authSessionParentId=aa9ac3df-dadc-4abc-bfea-022b27ca35f0, authSessionTabId=XmE45k_yHPg
```

I see `user_not_found` although it exists and I have set the credentials as well.

**Is there any other configuration needed for this user to be enabled?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you created a new realm, and created a user *in that realm*. The "redirect_uri" in your log entry suggests that you tried to log into the master realm's account console (http://localhost:8080/realms/master/account). Realms are separated from each other regarding users. You'll have to log into your newly created realm's account console, rather than the master realm's account console.

*The issue can be fixed by changing the URL to* (updating the `realm` as suggested)

http://localhost:8080/realms/**myrealm**/account/

Comment: Well I thought the same but how do I do that since there is no separate option of selecting or assigning a user to that realm

Comment: Edited to append the resolution as well, the issue can be fixed by changing the URL to use my newly created realm instead of `master` default